# Is it possible to read gradle variables from Android resources xml file?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm now in the process of migrating all my Maven config to Gradle.
One thing that I liked with maven was the 'properties-maven-plugin', allowing me to declare all my configurable properties in a .properties file (like key=value) and reference that property in a Android xml file, like:

```
<string name="my_server">${my.server.url}</string>
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing with Gradle, if possible keeping all my .properties file untouched.

I'm thinking I could write a new Gradle task that reads the contents of the .properties file, checks each value if it's a string/int/float/etc and generate the necessary XML, but that seems like a real pain.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter resources while copying them, have a look [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html), hint: `ReplaceTokens`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is somewhat I was thinking - writing a separate Gradle task to achieve this. However, if I were to go with ReplaceTokens, then in the task I must add a replace statement for every property name - in my case, that would be ~50 statements. This also means maintaining the property names from the Gradle task sync'ed with the ones from the .properties file.

Comment: You place all properties in a properties file, and then in the single task read them all, convert to map and pass as an argument for `ReplaceTokens`.